# XAMPP MySQL in Terminal is using a different instance

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have XAMPP installed and it's working fine in phpmyadmin. When i go to the command line it seems to be using a different instance of mysql, the password is blank instead of my password and when I run show databases it's a different set of databases.

I ran which mysql and got /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql, which is correct. If I stop mysql via the XAMPP ui, trying to run the mysql command from the command line fails with:
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket...
which is expected.

I've stopped the native mysql instance. I don't understand how I am not connecting to the same mysql db on the command line, it all looks fine. Any assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: Is the phpmyadmin you are connecting to on your localhost or on a website?

Comment: This is on my localhost. I'm running mac mavericks.

Comment: So you understand that your localhost database is completely separate from your website database, right? Meaning, anything you have done on your localhost will not appear on your website unless you've created the exact same tables, etc.. and vice versa

Comment: I'm a web developer and I've been doing this for a while :-)

Comment: I noticed that the native mysql was starting itself, so I checked and I had an old PATH alias to MAMP in bash_profile (still doesn't really explain why the native on started). I fixed up bash_profile but still had no luck. I just needed to get things moving on a project so I went back and reinstalled XAMPP thinking that should fix the issue and it partially has. Only the XAMPP mysql was running when I went to bed, now they're both running.

Comment: I need to kill off both of the processes in terminal, then run sudo mysql stop before I can start the XAMPP one up again. I'm pretty lost at this stage, I can't figure out. There is obviously some process running that occasionally starts the native mysql.

Also, the log file is empty.